# how to make space between two bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, w3.css

You can see the below code I'm trying to create two buttons in same line but its not work I want to make two button in same line in this code

```
 <div class="w3-show-inline-block">
  <div class="w3-bar">
    <button class="btn btn-success"  onClick={() => this._filterByYear('2006')}>2006</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success"  onClick={() => this._filterByYear('2007')}>2007</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-show-inline-block">
  <div class="w3-bar">
    <button class="btn btn-success"  onClick={() => this._filterByYear('2008')}>2008</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success"  onClick={() => this._filterByYear('2009')}>2009</button>
```

In demo code here why no space between two button i want like this https://ibb.co/rFD6knk

[Demo](https://codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv)

Comment: if anyone help me its very thankful for help and support

Comment: i want to make two button between space like this https://ibb.co/rFD6knk

Comment: anybody please help me why two button make not space you can see and check here also codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv

Comment: https://codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS :

```
button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
}
```

Here margin-left will give you the space between two , I have added more styling option here which will help you.

The `margin-left` and `margin-top` gives space, the `background` changes the background of the button, the `padding` adds space inside the button, and `border` gets rid of the default border.

Comment: Thanks for help and support and i want body part like this https://ibb.co/rFD6knk like in one card in one image.here its working https://codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv  but i implement in project setup its not work here you can see code https://github.com/namratasoni-coder/react_pro

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution. Just paste this into your css:

```
.w3-bar {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help and support and i want body part like this ibb.co/rFD6knk like in one card in one image.here its working codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv but i implement in project setup its not work here you can see code github.com/namratasoni-coder/react_pro

Answer (score 0):

These styles would do.

```css
.w3-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.w3-btn {
  max-width: fit-content;
}

nav {
  max-width: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

<del>[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bertdida/pen/poyJRpd)</del>

Comment: Thanks for help and support and i want body part like this ibb.co/rFD6knk like in one card in one image.here its working codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv but i implement in project setup its not work here you can see code github.com/namratasoni-coder/react_pro

Comment: help me out i m facing isuue

Comment: I updated my answer with `nav` and `img` styles. You can check on the CodePen link above.

Comment: thanks for help in code pen work fine BUT i m implement the react project its not work image card.

Comment: you can check here https://github.com/namratasoni-coder/react_pro